# Mount and boot using Virtualbox an OS that is installed on a dedicated physical disk

Tags: linux, hard-drive, windows-10, virtualbox

Background - I am dualbooting Win10 and Kubuntu 14.04.

Windows 10 has it's own 240 GB SSD (C:) and a 1 TB drive (D:).

Under Disk Management

- C: shows as Disk 2
- D: shows as Disk 1.

Disk 0 is a 240 GB SSD which I use as my Linux home partition and I have another 2 TB HDD for Linux data which shows as Disk 3 in Windows 10.

Now, I want to use my Linux partitions within VirtualBox after booting up Windows 10. Following [this](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch09.html#rawdisk) documentation as well as [this](http://www.serverwatch.com/server-tutorials/using-a-physical-hard-drive-with-a-virtualbox-vm.html), I open up the `cmd` prompt rom windows and type in:

```
VBoxManage.exe internalcommands createrawvmdk -filename "C:\Users\jrobe\VirtualBox VMs\Jarvis\jrvs_ptr.vmdk" -rawdisk \\.\PhysicalDrive0
```

which does, indeed, create the `.vmdk` file, but when I go to boot it from within VBox, it tells me `FATAL: No bootable medium found! System halted.`

Any ideas how to boot to this device? All I really want to do is to be able to edit contents on Disk 0 and Disk 3 from within Windows 10. I would also be open to creating a new VM and just mounting these locations, but I'm not sure how to do that.

Comment: I am not dualbooting with Vbox. I am actually dualbooting. I want the ability to boot *totally* to the Linux OS but also access the Linux OS from within Windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue might be that you have boot loader on Disk 2

So when you are creating a virtual machine using physical hard drive it's missing the boot loader

Inside your VM :

- add a virtual disk it can be like 2GB vmdk
- and also add your Disk 0 and Disk 3

Now next step is to add boot loader on this virtual disk. and this boot loader would load the OS from your Disk 0 or Disk 3 wherever it exits

[How to manually install boot loader?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/126541/how-to-manually-install-boot-loader)

Comment: Sounds reasonable, however when I make the small disk and boot into the live CD, then run `grub-install --recheck --no-floppy --root-directory=/ /dev/sda`, I get `grub-install: error: failed to get canonical path of '/cow'`